# keep only the last word in the sequence

Tags: r, string

I want to keep only the last word in the sequence. Also, there are specific words that I want to keep and don't remove if it appears in the sequence, and it should go the first of the sequence.

Let say I have two dictionaries of words.

```
myDictionary<-c("A","B","C","p")
Priority_dic<-c("p")
```

here, Proprity_dic shows the words that I want to keep if it appears wherever in the sequence.

I want to remove all words (in myDictionary) in the sequence and keep only the last word. Also, if Priority_dic appear in the sequence, put it in the first.

for example
I have a sequence

```r
df<-read.table(text="
id  mySequece
1   AAAB
2   ABABC
3   ApBpA
4   AACBBCp
5   ppp",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

result

```
id  mySequece
1   B
2   C
3   pA
4   pC
5   p
```

Comment: What do you want to do with letters that are in the sequence, but not in `myDictionary` or `Priority_dic`?

Comment: yes you right @akrun. sorry for bad English let me edit it and make it clearer

Comment: @Cina I made an edit to make thiis more general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `substring` with a condition.  After removing the `Priority_dic` element with `gsub`, get the last character with `substring`, then use `ifelse` to `paste` the Priority_dic with the substring output

```
v1 <- gsub(Priority_dic, "", df$mySequece)
v2 <- substring(v1, nchar(v1))
ifelse(grepl(Priority_dic, df$mySequece), paste0(Priority_dic, v2), v2)
#[1] "B"  "C"  "pA" "pC" "p"
```

---

Or to make it more general, we can extract based on the dictionary elements

```
v1 <- sapply(regmatches(df$mySequece, gregexpr(paste(myDictionary, 
  collapse="|"), df$mySequece)), function(x) tail(x[!x %in% Priority_dic], 1)[1])
i1 <- grepl(paste(Priority_dic, collapse="|"), df$mySequece)
v1[is.na(v1)] <- ""
ifelse(i1, paste0(Priority_dic, v1), v1)
#[1] "B"  "C"  "pA" "pC" "p"
```

Comment: the first code does not work on actual my data. Because it has characters with space like "zero top low high P high". However, the second one works. Thank you